# SQL Concurrent delete locking

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency, transactions

Some Background Information:
The data is regularly updated by deleting the old data and inserting the new.
The data is clustered into profiles which I use as part of the primary key and for deleting the old data.
Only a single Process writes data so don't have to worry about update conflicts by someone else.
Other process only read the data which i planned to solve via Snapshot-Isolation.
I access the data via entity framework 6, code first modeling.

The problem:
I start the gathering of data for several profiles parallel. Works fine for all tables with simple foreign key relation but for one with a self reference.

```
public class Web
{
    public Web()
    {
        CacheDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid ProfileGuid { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public Guid WebId { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public virtual List<List> Lists { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Web> SubWebs { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentProfileGuid { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentWebId { get; set; }

    public virtual Web ParentWeb { get; set;}
}

 modelBuilder.Entity<CacheWeb>()
     .HasMany(e => e.SubWebs)
     .WithOptional(e => e.ParentWeb)
     .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.ParentProfileGuid, e.ParentWebId })
     .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Due to performance issues i don't use the EF to delete the data but custom sql commands: `InsertContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String.Format("DELETE FROM Webs WHERE ProfileGuid = '{0}'", profile.Guid));`

If i call two of these deletes in concurrent transactions, the first call creates a lock which prevents the second transaction to continue.

As far as i can tell, the lock is somehow connected to the Index of the self-reference.

I just found another strange behavior, it depends on which transaction deletes first.
The only difference in the data i can find is the depth of the parent-child relation.
If i run transaction A first (has one parent and a few direct children) i can't run transaction B (has some parent->child->childchild relations) afterwards but if i run B first i can run A afterwards without getting into trouble with existing locks.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Or any idea what could be the problem with the lock? 
If you need more information please comment on what exactly you need, as I am not really sure what's important.

EDIT: for clarification

```
BEGIN Transaction t1
DELETE FROM Webs WHERE ProfileGuid = 'b35dbba4-54fc-4df7-b1c8-e559d81dfee3'
BEGIN Transaction t2
DELETE FROM Webs WHERE ProfileGuid = 'b35dbba4-54fc-4df7-b1c8-e559d81dfee4'
```

works. Swap the order and t1 has to wait for t2 to finish.

EDIT2: Execution Plans 
[image: Seek]
[image: Scan]

EDIT3: Model and full queries
[image: model_s]
The Execution plan is from the 3rd query (deleting of CacheList)

```
BEGIN Transaction t1
DELETE FROM CacheItems WHERE ProfileGuid = 'B35DBBA4-54FC-4DF7-B1C8-E559D81DFEE3'
DELETE FROM CacheFolders WHERE ProfileGuid = 'B35DBBA4-54FC-4DF7-B1C8-E559D81DFEE3'
DELETE FROM CacheLists WHERE ProfileGuid = 'B35DBBA4-54FC-4DF7-B1C8-E559D81DFEE3'
DELETE FROM CacheWebs WHERE ProfileGuid = 'B35DBBA4-54FC-4DF7-B1C8-E559D81DFEE3'
```

Comment: Can you run a SQL Server trace using the TSQL_Locks template and post the deadlock graph? That would show the exact details of the deadlock

Comment: I tried it and it didn't writing anything to the deadlock event file. Probably because there is no deadlock? (never used the graph before). As soon as i commit one transaction the other one runs smoothly. But as one transaction can take up to an hour waiting isn't relay an option.

Comment: You would see a series of events like Lock:Deadlock Chain, Deadlock Graph.

Comment: The delete queries don't seem to correlate to the plans. Can you add the table structure and also the non-clustered indexes? Then I can recreate the scenario.

Comment: My bad, the error occurs now in another query, i will add the fully table structure and the new query

Comment: Added the model, and all the queries. I found a rather dirty solution. If disable the option Enforce Foreign Key Constraint it works (isn't checking for violations during delete). I only could disable this via the designer, is there an option to do so via an sql query or entity framework?

Comment: Can you confirm that all primary keys start with ProfileGuid? You can do this by generating a CREATE TABLE script and confirming that ProfileGuid is always the first in the list of columns in the primary key definition.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can lock different levels depending on each particular query. That could explain why changing the order can make a transcation lock the other or not.

The ways to avoid the locks are

- setting a new [transaction isolation level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx), for the whole transaction/connection, which can also be done using TransactionScopes instanced with any [constuctor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) that supports TransactionOption to specify [IsolationLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx).
- using [table hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) to control how the table is locked, or read

Both of these solutions are dangerous, because lower isolation levels can lead to all kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to have complete isolation between transactions. That is, two transactions don't need to touch the same records.

When you divide the records into parallelized groups, records that share an id should be in the same group. A simple Parallel.Foreach isn't enough. The data inside each group can be processed sequentially without sharing any data with another parallel group.

As well as this logical isolation in your application you will need to make sure that the different queries are isolated from each other at an index node level. Make sure that all queries use an index seek and never a scan. This will avoid two queries putting an S lock (shared lock) on the same record while searching for records and then failing to convert that to an X lock when they try to delete. Run each of your queries with Show Actual Execution Plan and make sure that you see no index scans. If you see a scan and don't understand why then post a comment.

Comment: Thank you, Index Scan seems to be the problem. One of the querys uses Index Scan or Index Seek depending on the profile i am deleting. I added the execution plans, maybe you can take a look at it and give me an advise.